# text rotation 180 degree in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

How to rotate text 180 degree in crystal report?
I'm using visual studio 2005 with c#.
There's text rotation angle property in crystal report but there's no 180 degree.
I don't want to use image.
I want to display some data are rotate 0 degree, some are 180 degree, some are 270 degree.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Text rotated 180 degrees would be upside down. Why would you want that?

Comment: I want to test printing baggage tag which format include upside down characters using crystal report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're free upside down fonts on the net but they're not suitable for me.
So I create my own font with [Type light](http://www.cr8software.net/typelight.html) free font creator for upside down font. It's a nice software.