# 180 degrees on crystal report on Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, report

How I can set text rotation to 180 degrees on a crystal report? See the sample I created from a word file.
I see only 0, 90 and 270 in visual studio.

[image]
[image]

Note: We developed vs + crystal report on windows desktop software.

Comment: Relate issue : https://answers.sap.com/questions/422854/180-degrees-on-crystal-report-on-visual-studio-201.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [text rotation 180 degree in crystal report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171348/text-rotation-180-degree-in-crystal-report)

Comment: Another approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124755/how-do-i-rotate-a-text-45-degrees-in-crystal-reports

Comment: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1032435

Comment: It's fixed when I used on font up side down :)